# Rectangle event handler not working unless Fill property is set: why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I declared a `UniformGrid` in my XAML file:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8" Background="OliveDrab" 
    Name="board" Width="400" Height="400"/>
```

Then, I would like to programmatically add Rectangle children to it, and attach an event handler to each of them:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    createGrid();
}

private void createGrid()
{
    SolidColorBrush scb = Brushes.Olive;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Stroke = scb;
        r.MouseLeftButtonDown += Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        board.Children.Add(r);
    }
}

private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown");
}
```

But when I run the app and click on a `Rectangle`, the `Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown` is never called, unless I set a `Fill` property:

```
private void createGrid()
{
    SolidColorBrush scb = Brushes.Olive;
    SolidColorBrush whiteScb = Brushes.White;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.Stroke = scb;
        r.Fill = whiteScb;
        r.MouseLeftButtonDown += Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        board.Children.Add(r);
    }
}
```

Then and only then, the event is triggered.

So my question is: why must the `Fill` property of a `Rectangle` be set in order to make the event handler work?

Thanks.

**Edit:** as King King pointed, it looks like transparent windows don't send mouse events. More info: ['Transparent Windows in WPF' on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/09/09/transparent-windows-in-wpf.aspx).

Comment: looks like clicking on transparent region won't fire event, that's a normal behavior in windows.

Comment: Well thanks, it is indeed the reason behind it. Edited post with the info I found about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because  you don't set the `Fill` property, the `Rectangle`'s background will be transparent, and transparent controls are also "transparent" to mouse click. Hit testing goes straight to the first non-transparent control under it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a transparent rectangle which can be clicked then try

```
r.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
r.Opacity = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

However, you can set the Rectangle's `Fill` property to `Transparent` and it will pass on hit test and send the needed mouse events while Rectangle remains transparent.